# The C programming language book example: maybe out of date?

Tags: c

I started learning C and a friend of mine (older than me) suggested `The C Programming Language` by **Brian Kernighan** and **Dennis Ritchie**.

How ever, while trying some of the examples, they act differently than expected, and not as written in the book.

For example, this one, that doesn't seem to work (prints nothing):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */

int main()
{
   int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
   state = OUT;
   nl = nw = nc = 0;

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      ++nc;
      if (c == '\n')
         ++nl;
      if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
         state = OUT;
      else if (state == OUT) {
         state = IN;
         ++nw;
      }
   }
   printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
   return 0;
}
```

Do you think I should keep reading this book, maybe there are only a few mistakes, and it's worth reading? Or there is a better book for C starters.

EDIT: My assumption was that sending the input with the `ENTER` key, will simulate `EOF`, which is not. `CTRL+Z`  does.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: This is an amazing book. If you can work your way through its examples and do ther exercises, you will have a solid base for exploring C on your own.

Comment: If `ENTER` triggered an end-of-file condition, it would be difficult or impossible to accept more than one line of input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works for me.

```
$ gcc c.c -o c
$ echo hello world | ./c
1 2 12
$
```

The program reads text from standard input until it reached end-of-file. I suspect you just haven't signaled the end-of-file condition properly when reading from the keyboard. On Linux and other Unix-like systems, type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on a line by itself. On Windows, type <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.

If you launch the program from an IDE, it might run the program in a newly launched terminal window that closes when the program finishes; in that case, the window might disappear before you can see the output. If your IDE doesn't provide a way to override this misbehavior, you can either run it directly from a terminal window running a shell, or you can add a line such as:

```
getchar();
```

to the end of the program, before the `return 0;`.  This causes it to read (and ignore) a character of input before terminating; you can type <kbd>Enter</kbd> after seeing the output.  Note that this kind of thing can make running your program more awkward when you execute it from a shell, so do this only if necessary.

"The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, commonly referred to as K&R, is an excellent C book; Ritchie, after all, largely invented the language, though it does tend to assume some existing programming knowledge. Be sure you have the second edition; the first describes an earlier version of the language. (There have been two new ISO C standards since K&R2 was published, but they don't add anything that's critical for an introductory test.)

For a list of other C online tutorials and books, see questions 18.9 and 18.10 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 4):

K&R has received a lot of "bandwagon hype" because of nostalgia and because it was written by Dennis Ritchie. And it is without doubt the most famous programming book ever written. Yet, in my opinion it is not a good book for beginners.

The main reason is that the book was written before good programming style was invented. Most examples are written in what most modern C programmers would find to be a rather messy coding style. What is good and bad coding style is certainly a subjective topic. But take your example. It could be rewritten as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */

int main (void)
{
   int  ch;
   int  linefeeds_n = 0;
   int  words_n     = 0;
   int  chars_n     = 0;
   bool new_word    = true;


   while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) 
   {
     if (ch == '\n')
     {
       new_word = true;       
       linefeeds_n++;
     }
     else if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
     {
       new_word = true;
     }
     else if (new_word)
     {
       new_word = false;
       words_n++;
     }

     chars_n++;
   }

   printf("%d %d %d\n", 
          linefeeds_n, 
          words_n, 
          chars_n);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I find the above style more readable and correct. Changes are:

- Sane variable names.
- Readable variable declaration lists.
- No mysterious state variable. Use bool type instead.
- Always use {} for every statement to prevent numerous classic bugs.
- No multiple check against '\n' (faster code).
- Counter increment at the end of a while loop (common coding style).
- Correct way to end main() as per C99.
- Nitpick about main(), declared as void rather than empty parenthesis.

They are no big changes, no major issues, but it all quickly piles up...

This code was also written using features from the latest C99/C11 standards, something you won't find in K&R, since the book is also not up to date with the latest C standards.

Furthermore there are a few cases in K&R where the book is just incorrect, or where it preaches blatantly dangerous practice. One perfect example of such is: typecasting the result of malloc. More examples with valid criticism of the book can be found in [this article](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych55.html).

As there are numerous bugs, errors and typos, so make sure to always have the [errata](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) within reach when reading K&R.

Comment: -1: using an object of type `char` to hold the result of `getchar()` is a **big NO-NO**. See http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: @pmg Oops thanks for pointing that out. It was just a quick fix to get rid of compiler warnings. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

That program works fine.  Please note that it is expecting some input before it prints anything; it counts the number of lines, words, and characters in the input.  So if you compiled the code into `example` and ran:

```
echo this has four words | example
```

You would see as output:

```
1 4 20
```

(That's 1 line, 4 words, 20 characters).

Answer (score 2):

So, your program probably just prints nothing, but does not give you a prompt until you hit Ctrl+C or something like that, right? It means that you never exit the while loop, which means your input doesn't have EOF in it.

That book is based on older architectures which may have different conventions for what constitutes an EOF. My advice on the book is to continue with it, keeping a flexible mind so that you can interpret the errors and work around them. Learning from books is great, but you won't really integrate it until you start playing around with it and debugging it yourself. For example, if I didn't know what was going on in this program, I might put a printf inside the while loop to get some feedback about the looping behavior. I might also experiment with changing EOF to something else (maybe -1, ., //). Imagine you are a small child just playing with things and you will probably learn a lot faster. That's my experience at least.

As for other books to learn from, I highly highly recommend the book "Hacking, the Art of Exploitation" by Jon Erickson. It does not require previous experience programming, and the second chapter is a very thorough introduction to C. I learned more about how computers really work from that one chapter of the book than in 3 semesters of computer programming courses at a private university. In a very clear but dense manner, it explains how to use the GNU debugger, how the compiler interprets the code you write, how the memory works (stack, bss, etc) and most importantly, it explains how to see other things in life as programs (law, biology, etc). Also the rest of the book will teach you a huge amount of useful information, if you have the perseverance to get thru it.

Good luck and happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. It really shouldn't be outdated since the language hasn't changed much in quite some time. Some examples that exist on the internet and in books can be operating system specific. A classic example of this is `system("PAUSE");` which only works on Windows but can be converted to a sentinel loop that keeps asking if you want run it again or have a menu of options. I ran this example and hit ctrl-d and it outputted `5 3 14`. Below is my input. The last two are blank lines.

```
bla
blah
2
```

I typically run programs like these by redirecting the input such as `./a.out < a.in` on *nix

Answer (score 0):

《The C Programming Language》 is a very good book for you, trust you friend.
The reason nothing you see, is that you not end your input.
In Unix like so, you can input **Ctrl + D**, to end of your input.
The program is Ok, I test it.

Answer (score -2):

The C programming language is a good book by Dennis Ritchie. However, if you are feeling unsatisfied by it, you can use another book:
Let Us C-by Yashwant Kanetkar
After you finish of the book and you want to see how much of C you really know(that is, how much do you know about its syntax and its quirks), you can try this:
Test Your C Skills-by Yashwant Kanetkar